# How to modify an update in Oracle so it performs faster?

Tags: oracle, rdbms

I have this query:

```
UPDATE   (
    SELECT   h.valid_through_dt, h.LAST_UPDATE_TMSTMP
    FROM   ETL_FEE_SCH_TMP d, FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL h
    WHERE       h.FUND_ID = d.FUND_ID
    AND h.FEETYPE_NAME = d.FEETYPE_NAME
    AND h.BREAKPOINT_TYPE = d.BREAKPOINT_TYPE
    AND h.BREAKPOINT_QTY = d.BREAKPOINT_QTY
    AND h.LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT = d.LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT
    AND h.VALID_THROUGH = TO_DATE ('31-DEC-9999', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
    AND h.universe = 'DC'
    AND h.universe = d.universe
    AND EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM FEE_SCHEDULE s
        WHERE s.FUND_ID = h.FUND_ID
        AND s.FEETYPE_NAME = h.FEETYPE_NAME
        AND s.BREAKPOINT_TYPE = h.BREAKPOINT_TYPE
        AND s.BREAKPOINT_QTY = h.BREAKPOINT_QTY
        AND s.LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT = h.LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT
        AND s.universe = 'DC'
    )
) updateTable
SET     updateTable.VALID_THROUGH = (SYSDATE - 1),
updateTable.LAST_UPDATE_TMSTMP = SYSTIMESTAMP;
```

The trouble that I am having is that this query takes a long time to run. I don't know whether it is possible to run this on parallel, or it would be easier to update a cursor in a pipeline function.

What would you suggest?

This is all the information that I believe it is relevant.

This is the execution plan of the internal select:

```
Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 57376096
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                          |     1 |   306 |  8427   (1)| 00:01:42 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                |                          |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS               |                          |     1 |    306|  8427   (1)| 00:01:42 |
|   3 |    MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN      |                          |     1 |    192|  8426   (1)| 00:01:42 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN         | SYS_C000666              |     1 |     96|     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     BUFFER SORT              |                          |  3045K|   278M|  8425   (1)| 00:01:42 |
|   6 |      SORT UNIQUE             |                          |  3045K|   278M|  8425   (1)| 00:01:42 |
|*  7 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL      | FEE_SCHEDULE             |  3045K|   278M|  8425   (1)| 00:01:42 |
|*  8 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | FEE_SCHDL_IDX1           |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  9 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL  |     1 |   114 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
   4 - access("D"."UNIVERSE"='DC')
   7 - filter("S"."UNIVERSE"='DC')
   8 - access("H"."UNIVERSE"='DC' AND "S"."FUND_ID"="H"."FUND_ID" AND
              "S"."FEETYPE_NAME"="H"."FEETYPE_NAME" AND
              "S"."BREAKPOINT_TYPE"="H"."BREAKPOINT_TYPE" AND
              "S"."BREAKPOINT_QTY"="H"."BREAKPOINT_QTY" AND
              "S"."LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT"="H"."LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT")
       filter("H"."FUND_ID"="D"."FUND_ID" AND
              "H"."FEETYPE_NAME"="D"."FEETYPE_NAME" AND
              "H"."BREAKPOINT_TYPE"="D"."BREAKPOINT_UNIT_TY
```

Table data:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UNIVERSE|FUND_ID   |FEETYPE_NAME |BREAKPOINT_TYPE|BREAKPOINT_QTY|LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT|HIGH_BREAKPOINT_AMT|FEE_PCT|FEE_SCHDL_SEQ_ID|GROUP_ID|LAST_UPDATE_TMSTMP  |VALID_FROM|VALID_THROUGH|INSERT_TMSTMP        |JOB_ID|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DC      |DC9ZTPLPHO|DeferLoad    |Percentage     |4             |10000             |300000             |3.14   |780250          |null    |1/4/2012  3:59:54 PM|6/23/2012 |12/31/9999   |1/5/2011   3:59:54 PM|666   |
DC      |DCE86Y8XFU|RedemptionFee|Percentage     |9             |  100             |100500             |7.67   |780251          |null    |6/4/2012  4:49:54 PM|11/12/2011|12/31/9999   |8/17/2011  2:00:54 PM|666   |
DC      |DCAYL0KONA|FrontLoad    |Percentage     |2             |50000             |601500             |5.00   |780252          |null    |4/25/2012 4:49:54 PM|8/2/2012  |12/31/9999   |12/19/2012 9:59:00 PM|666   |
DC      |DC9ZTPLPHO|DeferLoad    |Percentage     |7             |80000             |900000             |2.24   |780252          |null    |4/25/2012 4:49:54 PM|8/2/2012  |12/31/9999   |12/19/2012 9:59:00 PM|666   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the script of the historical table:

```
CREATE TABLE FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL
(
  UNIVERSE                        VARCHAR2(2 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  FUND_ID                         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  FEETYPE_NAME                    VARCHAR2(75 BYTE),
  BREAKPOINT_TYPE                 VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  BREAKPOINT_QTY                  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT              NUMBER(19,6),
  HIGH_BREAKPOINT_AMT             NUMBER(19,6),
  FEE_PCT                         NUMBER(19,6),
  FEE_SCHDL_SEQ_ID                NUMBER        NOT NULL,
  GROUP_ID                        NUMBER,
  LAST_UPDATE_TMSTMP              DATE          NOT NULL,
  VALID_FROM                      DATE          NOT NULL,
  VALID_THROUGH                   DATE          NOT NULL,
  INSERT_TMSTMP                   DATE          NOT NULL,
  JOB_ID                          NUMBER        NOT NULL
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FEE_SCHDL_PK ON FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL(FEE_SCHDL_SEQ_ID);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FEE_SCHDL_HST_IDX ON FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL (
    UNIVERSE,
    FUND_ID,
    FEETYPE_NAME,
    BREAKPOINT_TYPE,
    BREAKPOINT_QTY, 
    LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT,
    VALID_FROM,
    JOB_ID
)

CREATE INDEX FEE_SCHEDULE_HST_IDX2 ON FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL(LAST_UPDATE_TMSTMP)

CREATE INDEX FEE_SCHEDULE_HST_IDX3 ON FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL(VALID_THROUGH)

ALTER TABLE FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL ADD (
    CONSTRAINT FEE_SCHDL_PK
    PRIMARY KEY
    (FEE_SCHDL_SEQ_ID)
);
```

This is the other table:

```
CREATE TABLE FEE_SCHEDULE
(
  UNIVERSE                        VARCHAR2(2 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  FUND_ID                         VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  FEETYPE_NAME                    VARCHAR2(75 BYTE),
  BREAKPOINT_TYPE                 VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  BREAKPOINT_QTY                  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT              NUMBER(19,6),
  HIGH_BREAKPOINT_AMT             NUMBER(19,6),
  FEE_PCT                         NUMBER(19,6),
  JOB_RUN_ID                      NUMBER        NOT NULL,
  FILE_DATE                       DATE          NOT NULL,
  CYCLE_DATE                      DATE          NOT NULL
)
```

The temporary table is the result of FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL minus FEE_SCHEDULE

Comment: A question as detailed as this really should be on a DBA stack.

Comment: Wouldn't `..AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL..` always return false? Would this - `..AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1..` make more sense??

Comment: @Annjawn Hi, according to this https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=353014 NULL or 1 are only "symbolic" name (they are never used outside the sub-select).

Comment: Yes they are and I am aware of that. But its not what I asked? `SELECT NULL...` is plain confusing and shouldn't be used (unless you are using a `UNION`).

Comment: @StrayChild01 if FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL + ETL_FEE_SCH_TMP = FEE_SCHEDULE, why do you perform additional costly FTS `exists` check for FEE_SCHEDULE at all, if you are somewhat sure to have all the data in former two tables which you joined? doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Did you try to add an index on `fee_schedule (universe, fund_id, feetype_name, breakpoint_type, breakpoint_qty, low_breakpoint_amt)`. Maybe one on `universe, fund_id`  is already good enough to turn that FTS into an index scan.

Comment: @beherenow You're totally right, I misplaced the minus. It is FEE_SCHEDULE + ETL_FEE_SCH_TMP = FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, I already tried that and it continued performing a full table scan. Weirdly, the explain and cost didn't change. Also, universe and fund id can be repeated, because one fund can have several fees of the same type.

Comment: I don't see the definition for ETL_FEE_SCH_TMP.  Also, there seems to be some other DDL missing because as is your query will get `ORA-0779: cannot modify a column wich maps to a non key-preserved table`.

Comment: Did you notice that there's a cartesian there? Also, there's any chance you could create a new table instead of updating and then switching partitions/renaming them?

Comment: As far as I can see Oracle estimates that your select-statement returns about oen row. 1. Does it return about one row? 2. What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Check EXPLAIN PLAN output id 7 TABLE ACCESS FULL on table FEE_SCHEDULE ? The query looks like a correlated subquery to me maybe you should rewrite it to a INNER JOIN to get more performance

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that your `FEE_SCHEDULE` table is a lot smaller than the `FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL` table, so you might want to exploit `EXISTS` a little more. Dipping into the `FEE_SCHEDULE` table on a row-by-row basis can be a relatively cheap operation compared to joining it to all the rows in the `FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL` .

Since the `ETL_FEE_SCH_TMP` table is the `FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL` minus `FEE_SCHEDULE`, you can actually accomplish the update with just a couple of `EXISTS` statements, without all the joins and saving you the trouble of creating the temp table. You don't really need the temp table.

I think this might be worth a look :

```
update FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL H
set H.VALID_THROUGH = (sysdate - 1), H.LAST_UPDATE_TMSTMP = SYSTIMESTAMP
where 
    H.VALID_THROUGH = TO_DATE ('31-DEC-9999', 'dd-mon-yyyy')
    AND H.universe = 'DC'
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1
        FROM FEE_SCHEDULE F
        WHERE 
            F.universe = H.Universe
            AND F.FUND_ID = H.FUND_ID
            AND F.FEETYPE_NAME = H.FEETYPE_NAME
            AND F.BREAKPOINT_TYPE = H.BREAKPOINT_TYPE
            AND F.BREAKPOINT_QTY = H.BREAKPOINT_QTY
            AND F.LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT = H.LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT
            AND F.HIGH_BREAKPOINT_AMT = H.HIGH_BREAKPOINT_AMT
            AND F.FEE_PCT = H.FEE_PCT
    )
    AND EXISTS
        (
        SELECT 1
        FROM FEE_SCHEDULE FF
        WHERE 
            FF.universe = 'DC'
            AND FF.FUND_ID = h.FUND_ID
            AND FF.FEETYPE_NAME = h.FEETYPE_NAME
            AND FF.BREAKPOINT_TYPE = h.BREAKPOINT_TYPE
            AND FF.BREAKPOINT_QTY = h.BREAKPOINT_QTY
            AND FF.LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT = h.LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT
  )
```

Also, consider adding an index to the `FEE_SCHEDULE` table, similar to the one on the `FEE_SCHEDULE_HISTORICAL`. That really helps the explain plan along.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX FEE_SCHDL_IDX ON FEE_SCHEDULE (
    UNIVERSE,
    FUND_ID,
    FEETYPE_NAME,
    BREAKPOINT_TYPE,
    BREAKPOINT_QTY, 
    LOW_BREAKPOINT_AMT
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running SQL Tuning Advisor for you statement? It usually finds missing indexes, statistics, costly operations etc. This is fairly easy to do using SQL developer eg. see http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/TuningAdvisor/TuningAdvisor.htm